# Cannot connect to local MQTT server (running on Windows 10) from docker instance

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, window, mqtt, iot

RabbitMQ server is running locally on Windows 10 and docker is running on it also.
I'm running a device simulator on docker and it has to talk to local RabbitMQ server through MQTT.
It had been working but one day it stopped.
Here is device logging -

```
mqtt-client.cpp:322 | Failed to connect to broker at 'xxx@xxx.xxxxxx.com/:1883': code=15, message='Lookup error.'
```

Keep in mind that from docker(latest version) calls have been made to local web server which has exact domain name -

```
https-commissioning-channel.cpp:81 | [HttpsCommissioningChannel] using token to contact bootstrap service at 'https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/apibst/alo/v1/bootstrap/device-info'
```

So you can see domain name has been resolved. For firewall configuration port is open on 1883 (consider it had been working). RabbitMQ is running.

What might be the issue and what should I do to make the call go through?

Comment: `xxx@xxx.xxxxxx.com/:1883` should not contain a slash (`xxx@xxx.xxxxxx.com:1883`) - see the [URI Scheme](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.org/wiki/URI-Scheme). This may not be your issue (as you say "one day it stopped") but is all I can spot in the info provided (supplying sample code and docker configuration may result in a better answer).

Comment: That's exactly the issue. Sometimes I just got numb looking at the stuff and it simply didn't click. Thank you Brits. How do I mark your reply as the answer?

Comment: I have posted this as an answer (you cannot accept a comment as an answer; I would have posted an answer directly if it was not for your comment "It had been working but one day it stopped.").

Comment: that endpoint came from config change and I wasn't aware that introduced a slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments `xxx@xxx.xxxxxx.com/:1883` should not contain a slash (`xxx@xxx.xxxxxx.com:1883`) - see the [URI Scheme](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.org/wiki/URI-Scheme).